# routing system it works not used angular 12

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am a beginner in `angular`, I followed a training, I reached routing system, I created routing system by command `ng g m routes --routing`, I declared routes, I changed tag `<home></home>` by `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
Nothing to show.

**home.component.html**

```
<sliders [rowOfSliders]="rowSliders"></sliders>
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="mt-5">Nos Services</h2>
    <hr>
    <services [rowOfServices]="rowServices"></services>
    
    <h2 class="mt-5">Nos Actualites</h2>
    <hr>
    <posts [rowsOfPosts]="rowPosts"></posts> 
</div>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<menu></menu>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { RoutesModule } from './routes/routes.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { AcceuilComponent } from './components/acceuil/acceuil.component';
import { BlogComponent } from './components/blog/blog.component';
import { BreadcrumbComponent } from './components/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './components/contact/contact.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './components/menu/menu.component';
import { MessageComponent } from './components/message/message.component';
import { PostsComponent } from './components/posts/posts.component';
import { ServiceComponent } from './components/service/service.component';
import { ServicesComponent } from './components/services/services.component';
import { ShowPostComponent } from './components/show-post/show-post.component';
import { ShowServiceComponent } from './components/show-service/show-service.component';
import { SlidersComponent } from './components/sliders/sliders.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    AcceuilComponent,
    BlogComponent,
    BreadcrumbComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    MessageComponent,
    PostsComponent,
    ServiceComponent,
    ServicesComponent,
    ShowPostComponent,
    ShowServiceComponent,
    SlidersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    RoutesModule
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas:[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You need to including routing modules and/or routing to your base app component. We'd need to see that before we could diagnose why.

Comment: @Z.Bagley thx for u answer, i add RoutesModule in app.module.ts

Comment: @Z.Bagley it works fine when I change the <router-outlet></router-outlet> tag to <home></home>

Comment: Excellent. Next couple items is making sure you're providing the router module in root, and then verifying that you are actually going to the defined route (and it's defined properly). Update your question to include your AppModule and RoutesModule code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular routing routes a url path to a component like so:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ComponentToRoute } from './myComponentPath/myComponent.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "ComponentPath", component: ComponentToRoute }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

When navigating to the `localhost:4200/ComponentPath` the `<router-outlet>` will output the component listed on that url path.

If this is how your Routing Module looks like it might be missing references in your `app.module.ts` it should look like this:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ComponentToRoute } from './myComponentPath/myComponent.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ComponentToRoute 
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: thx for u answer i add app.module.ts

Comment: If the issue was resolved don't forget to mark the answer ;)

Comment: I got an error : `vendor.js:50954 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ChildrenOutletContexts -> ChildrenOutletContexts -> ChildrenOutletContexts]: `

Comment: What does your RoutesModule look like?
Also this "MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot()" looks out of place.